# Struggling with basic Swift logic (Working with constants, variables and loops)

Tags: swift, firebase

I want to use 2 Strings that I get with those two "loops" from firebase and use them in another "loop" to upload them with a bunch of other Information.

My problem is, that I somehow can't get the values of `fullname` and `pfp` that I downloaded, into the upload to firebase.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

```
func sendToFire(){
    let combined = "\(userID)" + "\(number)"
    let docRef = db.collection("posts").document(combined)
    let description = self.textPost.text
    let nameRef = db.collection("users").document(userID)
    var fullname = ""
    var pfp = ""

    if fireImage == nil {

       nameRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
           if let document = document{
               fullname = document.get("fullname") as! String
           }else{
               print("Coulnt get fullname")
           }
       }

       nameRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
           if let document = document{
               pfp = document.get("profileimage") as! String
           }else{
               print("Couldn't get profileimage")
           }
       }

       docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
           if let document = document, document.exists {
               print("Post ID already taken")
           } else {
               print("Post Document gets created")
               self.db.collection("posts").document(combined).setData([
                   "description": description!,
                   "likes": self.likes,
                   "postType": 0,
                   "profileImage": pfp,
                   "time": self.date,
                   "uid": self.userID,
                   "username": fullname
               ]) { err in
                   if let err = err {
                       print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                   } else {
                       print("Post Document successfully written!")
                   }
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is not executing in the proper sequence. Firebase is asynchronous and firebase data is only valid *within the closure following the firebase function*. Code that immediately follows the closure may/will execute before the code in the closure. For example: This piece of code `.document(combined).setData` actually executes before this piece of code `fullname = document.get("fullname")`. So nothing will be written with setData. At other times it may work! You need to work with Firebase data in the order the data is retrieved; wait for full name, then wait for profileImage, *then* setData

Answer (score 0):

Add **`document.exists`** in the **if let**

```
        nameRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists{
                fullname = document.get("fullname") as! String
            }else{
                print("Coulnt get fullname")
            }
        }

        nameRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists{
                pfp = document.get("profileimage") as! String
            }else{
                print("Couldn't get profileimage")
            }
        }
```

Check the actual key names in the response `fullname` and `profileimage`.

Comment: I added the ```document.exists```, but this still doesnt solve the problem

Comment: is users db working fine ? also did you check the strings ?

Comment: This isn't going to work as Firebase is asynchronous and firebase data is only valid within the closure following the firebase function - in this case the OP's setData is being called *before the fullName and pfp are populated*, therefore empty strings are written.